# Why can a manifested creature be turned face up if it loses all it's abilities but a morphed card can't?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question is dedicated to a better understanding of a card: [Wildcall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWildcall%5d).  The Gather entry has the following ruling.

> "Unlike a face-down creature that was cast using the morph ability, a manifested creature may still be turned face up after it loses its abilities if it's a creature card."

**I would like to know its exact meaning, and possible use.** Thank you!

Comment: I really do not appreciate the editing done,because I have deliberately written the question very long,adding other news,especially dedicated to the less experienced players,and less experienced than many smartSEusers,which concern an almost complete explanation of the reasons related to other ruling.Thanks to DenisS:but I would also like to restore the part he deleted,forgetting that the question is not written by him.I disapprove of duplication for the same reason.My question would want to shed light onWildcall,with explanations of2of his rulings:it is less generic than the linked question.

Comment: P.S. Thank you DenisS,but  what you call "huge chunk of pointless text" may not be at all for me,as I remain the author of this question. This question is intentionally designed for beginners, unexperienced players unlike you, and therefore makes perfect sense with long writing and with the parts you have deleted. Moreover,in that way it is not even a duplicate, because it contains other info.So, Before twisting it, please ask me for a confirmation.This is not what may be called properly a "democratic action",as SE loudly asks, it seems to me. 
So please DenisS, check the code of conduct.

Comment: The fact is that those paragraphs about a different question and a different ruling are not relevant to the question being asked here. Irrelevant information like that does not benefit beginners or anyone else, and makes it harder to see what the main question is. If you want to ask about or provide information about how Manifest and ETB triggers interact, that belongs in a different question. I am removing that text again, please do not put it back.

Comment: It's not true at all what you say this time, Murgatroid. I thank you very much for the excellent answer you provided, but the information on the first part of the question is also useful for me, who is the author of the question. Indeed, I will say more: the first part that you deleted "IS" the question.

Comment: To prove it is my following step,present on the original question:"However,assuming that all the above is correct-if not,please tell me about any errors,in the same answer-this question is going,instead,to shed ... "-in which it is clarified that a novice(as there are many,and,given the constant changes in the rules,as I am too)can also be mistaken in understanding the first of the two rulings of which full explanation required.Your behavior is anti-democratic and unacceptable.I will report the question,and edit it again,because it is my request:not yours,Murgatroid,nor much less of DenisS.

Comment: 1) If I offended you or made you upset by calling the removed text "junk" I apologize. However, you need to why I took the actions I took.  The two "questions" that you had were not related to each other to make them suitable to be in a single question.  If you had questions about ETB effects on face down cards and morph creatures losing their morph ability, you should have asked two seperate questions.  Just because both questions are about face down cards doesn't mean that they should be in the same question.  Putting two unreleated questions together makes the site harder to navigate.

Comment: 2) Because of that, I decided to focus the question on the manifesting/morph ruling listed on the page for Wildcall. I did this for two reasons - you specifically mentioned at the end of your question that this was what you were asking about ("this question is going, instead, to shed light on another important ruling of this card.") , and you answer your own question about the ETB effects. I then closed the question because the Manifest/Humility and Morph/Humility interaction has already been answered on this site.

Comment: 3) Feel free to report this question if you feel you were unfairly treated, but the fact of the matter is that your question in its original form was unacceptable. I edited it to make it conform to the rules of this site. If you want to ask a question about ETB effects on face-down creatures, put it in a different question (in fact, I strongly encourage it). Don't combine multiple questions into a single post. And definitiely don't get into edit wars, especially when a diamond mod is involved.

Comment: First of all: 1) What is a "diamond mod"?; secondly ,2) You all really like too much to infuriate me artificially, it must be fun for you. I must say that you know how to do it, congratulations!; 3) I would like to know why Murgatroid immediately answered my question, without editing it first in the way it did after DenisS: if it had really been so "unacceptable", Murgatroid would surely have edited; but he did not: on the contrary, he replied very well, and immediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104775/discussion-between-manofromberlin-and-deniss).

Comment: Such an expression from Murgatroid  is "unacceptable": - "I am removing that text again, please do not put it back". But the question is written by me, how could you edit it twice, canceling what is a very important part for me? Also, why not edit it before answering, if it was really so wrong? I am very sorry that Murgatroid contradicts itself so blatantly ... it is a pity, because he is really very good in MTG, and he responds always very well, as he did also in this case, before the usual controversy towards me ...

Comment: Furthermore, there would be other things to say about the precise wording of the Gatherer Ruling that has been discussed in this question. Firstly, I criticize the wording "a face-down creature that was cast using the morph ability". It doesn't seem to me that a "face-down creature" could be "cast", since it's already in play; secondly , following the ruling as reported to the letter, a player should consider "to cast a creature" and "to unmorph a creature" as if they were both summoning operations, which do not seem to me the same thing, nor a similar thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Rule 702.36e](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Morph) describes how to turn a creature face up using a morph ability:

> Any time you have priority, you may turn a face-down permanent you control with a morph ability face up. This is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 116). To do this, show all players what the permanent’s morph cost would be if it were face up, pay that cost, then turn the permanent face up. **(If the permanent wouldn’t have a morph cost if it were face up, it can’t be turned face up this way.)** The morph effect on it ends, and it regains its normal characteristics. Any abilities relating to the permanent entering the battlefield don’t trigger when it’s turned face up and don’t have any effect, because the permanent has already entered the battlefield.

[Rule 701.33b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Manifest) describes how to turn a manifested creature face up:

> Any time you have priority, you may turn a manifested permanent you control face up. This is a special action that doesn’t use the stack (see rule 116.2b). To do this, show all players that the card representing that permanent is a creature card and what that card’s mana cost is, pay that cost, then turn the permanent face up. The effect defining its characteristics while it was face down ends, and it regains its normal characteristics. **(If the card representing that permanent isn’t a creature card or it doesn’t have a mana cost, it can’t be turned face up this way.)**

As you can see in the highlighted sections, a creature with Morph still needs to have the Morph ability to be turned face up that way, but the Manifest rules don't check whether the creature has any abilities. So, if the creature loses its abilities, it can't be turned face up using the Morph ability, but it can be turned face up using the Manifest effect. This is the difference that ruling is pointing to.

The reason for this difference is that Morph is an ability that the card has, and Manifest is something that is done to the card. So, turning a Morph creature face up uses the ability, but turning a Manifested creature face up uses an effect that was previously applied to the creature.

Face down Morph creatures are affected this way by effects that remove abilities because those effects are continuous effects, and if you turn a face down creature face up it is still the same permanent. As a result, a creature affected by an effect that removes abilities wouldn't have the Morph ability if it were turned face up, so it can't be turned face up using the Morph rule.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. And, in my opinion, very important,too. This is because a phrase that is often said, but which in this case is not very useful, is the fact that a card turned face down (but which has the morph ability when facing up) actually HAS at least one ability. Instead, it is said too often that a morphed card is completely out of abilities (like a 2/2 vanilla), and this is not entirely true. Now everything is much clearer.

Comment: A face down permanent does not have any abilities on its own. The rule I quoted is very particular about checking what "permanent’s morph cost would be if it were face up".

Comment: Ok,but I have some thing to say about it. If what Murgatroid says is true - and  surely it  is - it remains to be understood how a creature turned face down can lose its morph ability, which concerns the turned down  face of that card (the card itself), and not its morphed version (a 2/2 vanilla). If an effect hit the 2/2 vanilla , removing all its abilities, would it also be able to remove the morph ability?In other words,would it also be able to remove the ability present on the side of the card that is not currently visible? As far as I know, it seems to me a NOT practicable operation ...

Comment: Or in any case, it does not seem to me a viable operation, unless it is admitted that the 2/2 vanilla  actually has the morph ability, or at least that there is "some kind of  connection" between the 2/2 vanilla  and the morph ability present on the other side of the card ...

Comment: I have added a paragraph to try to explain why it works that way.

Comment: Very well. Now it is clear how that "some kind of connection" I mentioned in the previous comment - between the vanilla 2/2 and the morph ability that is on the other side of the card - works. In practice,1) "first" you turn the card to the opposite side, showing that it has morph ability; 2) and "then" you pay the morph cost. But, due to an eventual continuous effect, between the two steps just mentioned the creature loses all abilities, and therefore it is not possible to pay any morph costs anymore,because the creature has just lose morph. This seems to me a solution,thank you Murgatroid!